# Datatables fixed columns overlapping

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have taken vertical tabs code from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_vertical_tabs.asp and added a datatable to the top tab. Everything is working, but when I add the fixedColumns to the datatable, the columns overlap.[image]

If I take the fixed column out, the table looks correct. The only piece of code I changed is the first div(london). Can anyone help me? Here is the div code:

```
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
<h2>Search Results</h2>

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
<thead>

        <tr>
        <th class="text-warning h5">Account ID</th>
        <th class="text-warning h5">Account Name</th>
        <th class="text-warning h5">First Name</th>
        <th class="text-warning h5">Last Name</th>
        <th class="text-warning h5">Address1</th>
        <th class="text-warning h5">City </th>
        <th class="text-warning h5">State</th>
        <th class="text-warning h5">Zip</th>
        <th class="text-warning h5">Price</th>

        </tr>

</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-success h6">Account1</td>
        <td class="text-success h6">Account Name</td>
        <td class="text-success h6">Name1</td>
        <td class="text-success h6">Name2</td>
        <td class="text-success h6">ccccc</td>
        <td class="text-success h6">XX </td>
        <td class="text-success h6">FF</td>
        <td class="text-success h6">11111</td>
        <td class="text-success h6">2.222</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-success h6">Account1</td>
        <td class="text-success h6">Account Name</td>
        <td class="text-success h6">Name1</td>
        <td class="text-success h6">Name2</td>
        <td class="text-success h6">ccccc</td>
        <td class="text-success h6">XX </td>
        <td class="text-success h6">FF</td>
        <td class="text-success h6">11111</td>
        <td class="text-success h6">2.222</td>

    </tr>
    </tbody> 
    </table>
</div>
```

And this is the datatable initialization:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable({
    scrollY:        "600px",
    scrollX:        true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging:         true,
    fixedColumns:   {
        leftColumns: 2
    }
});
```

} );

Comment: One small point: In your table HTML, the body cells should all be `td` tags not `th` tags, I assume.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue.